# Properly integrating PagerJS with History.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, single-page-application, history.js, pagerjs

I'm trying to set up a SPA using Knockout, pagerjs, and history.js. However, when I click on a link containing `data-bind="'page-href': '/somepath'"`, I get a JS error:

> Object function History() { [native code] } has no method 'pushState'

This would indicate to me that I'm initializing pagerjs incorrectly, but I thought I was following the demo correctly. Here's how I'm initializing pagerjs:

```
define(['knockout', 'pager', 'history'], function (ko, pager, history) {
    // [define my view model]

    pager.useHTML5history = true;
    pager.Href5.history = history;
    pager.extendWithPage(viewModel);

    // [apply bindings]

    pager.start();
});
```

To enable history.js to load as an AMD module, I added this to the bottom of history.js:

```
// [original history.js code]

define(function() { return History; });
```

However, I notice that `History` does not have a `pushState` method, which is what pagerjs tries to call.

What is the correct way to integrate pagerjs and history.js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thankfully, I found [this unit test code](https://github.com/finnsson/pagerjs/blob/master/test_html5/should_work_with_history_js/index.html). Here's what I learned:

1. You must have a `<base href="..."/>` to specify your base URL.
2. You should not include the raw `history.js` file that's in Git, but use the `jquery.history.js` bundle.
3. Instead of using `pager.start()`, use `pager.startHistoryJs()`.

Here's my updated init code:

```
define(['knockout', 'pager', 'history'], function (ko, pager, history) {

    var viewModel = /* [Create my view model] */;

    pager.useHTML5history = true;
    pager.Href5.history = history;
    pager.extendWithPage(viewModel);

    ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

    pager.startHistoryJs();
});
```

And here's how I AMD-ized `jquery.history.js`:

```
define(['jquery'], function () {

    // [Original code]

    return History;
});
```